# syntax on nodejs function

Tags: node.js, function, syntax-error

I'm starting right now with coding on JS. There are a few things that I don't understand pretty well, and I'm a little bit confused because I have tried almost all, and I don't get to solve the error. Would someone provide me some help or guidance with this.

my code

```js
function ImparPar(NumIp) {
   if(NumIp % 2 === 0) {
      return 'Par';
   } else {
      return 'Impar';
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What  is `function ImagePar(2)` supposed to mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [why not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry, I'm new on this forum, didn't know that. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: That's OK, but you can still edit your question to put the code in as text. The question is in danger of being closed otherwise.

Comment: Thx for the edit Norbert! I was just about to edit it by myself, but thanks. You guys are very nice on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function definition (on Line 1) has the following:

- The `function` keyword
- A function name (ImparPar)
- A `formal` parameter (NumIP)

All these make this a function definition.

When you are calling the function later on in the code (line 13) you just need to call it by name. e.g.:

```js
ImparPar(2);
```

When you are calling a function, you pass it - what is called - an `actual` parameter (in your case `2`).

When you prefix it with the `function` keyword, it is interpreted as a function definition and therefore does not expect an `actual` parameter, and instead expects a formal parameter.

If you remove the `function` keyword from line 13 it should work as expected for you, and just execute the function.